# How to selectively disable warnings in javac for spring 4.1.1 release

Tags: java, spring, java-7, java-8, javac

We are in technology refresh mode - specifically spring libraries. We are getting warning

> Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'Repeatable': class file for java.lang.annotation.Repeatable not found

Since we treat warnings as errors, whole build fails. If I remove -Werror flag, project does compile and runs fine.

I know the cause of warning. We tried upgrading to java8, but looks like it will not be an option for us as other tooling does not work properly - e.g. eclipse luna simply crashes on java8/ubuntu combo many times. Eclipse indigo does not even want to start.

Our maven pom file mentions -Werror flag which is very valuable flag. Is there any way to disable just this warning? Or is there any other alternative solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `@SuppressWarnings` annotation could help you.

Comment: Where should I add this annotation?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html
"Indicates that the named compiler warnings should be suppressed in the annotated element (and in all program elements contained in the annotated element)."
So, just before the declaration of element which lead to warning appearance.